# What are the (red) marks to the right of the editor pane in Spyder 4?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Just updated Anaconda to get latest Spyder (4.0.1). What are the (red) marks flagged to the right of the editor window frame?

[SpyderEditor_MarkerBars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37o4x.png)

Comment: They're potential warnings or errors, at least that's what it is on most of the IDE's

Comment: The warnings/errors are shown on the left edge of the editor window, as a small red circle with an x in the middle (when you hover over them with your cursor, the warning/error message is displayed). But to the right of the editor window is still a mystery as to what those small (red) marker bars are

Comment: try hovering over the red lines and see if a text box popups up.

Comment: yes tried that but nothing there. Note, when I scroll the editor up and down, those red marks don't move

Answer (score 4):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The vertical bar on the right of the editor is Spyder's [minimap](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mini-map#/Code_Minimap_in_Text_editors_and_IDEs). It allows you to quickly move to the place errors (shown as red lines), warnings (yellow) or TODOs (blue) are located in your file by clicking on them.

Comment: Many thanks. OK so those little coloured bars on the right are more or less mini flags to alert a user, and they correspond to the errors/warnings/TODOs displayed on the left of the main editor window?

Comment: Thanks Carlos! BTW, I searched for this topic in the Spyder Help but couldn't find it

Comment: Sorry, our docs are a bit outdated and quite minimal. But we're improving them at the moment. New docs should be deployed in two months or so.